# Outlook.com send folder shows incorrect "to" addresses

Tags: outlook.com

I recently migrated all my gmail into outlook.com. I did that via POP3 fetch and my gmail **sent mail** went into my outlook.com **inbox**. I then fixed that by searching all mails with me as the sender and moved them (in bulk) to the **sent** folder of outlook.com. This was done via the WebApps's HTML/Browser UI itself.

Now when I view the sent items folder in Outlook.com directly (web browser), for some reason those mails I moved from the inbox => sent folder are still get listed with the "from" addresses only. This is seen below.

[image]

**How can I fix it so that they display the "to" addresses when living in the *sent* folder?**

*Update: When I sync Outlook.com with Outlook 2013, the "to" addresses are all proper; so I suspect this might be a bug in Outlook.com's HTML view renderer*.